# Issue with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers

I am working on an Openlayers based application. It basically renders an image and user can draw geometrical features like lines, polygons etc on the image by mouse click action.

I have to implement a feature wherein user can vary the image brightness by moving a slider.

I follow [this](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/image-filter.html) link.I have placed my pixel manipulation code in a method 'updateBrightness', as shown in the link.

```
imageLayer.on('postcompose', (event) => {
      this.updateBrightness(this.currentBrightness, event.context);
  });

updateBrightness(val, ctx) {

    if(ctx && this.currentImageData){
        ctx.putImageData(this.currentImageData, 0, 0);
        this.map.render;
        return;
    }
    var brightnessVar = val - this.currentBrightness;
    this.currentBrightness = val;
    var canvas = this.map.renderer_.canvas_;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;
    var output = ctx.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var outputData = output.data;

    console.log('Input length:' + imgData.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < imgData.length; i += 4) {
        outputData[i] = imgData[i] + brightnessVar;
        if(outputData[i] > 255) {
            outputData[i] = 255;
        }
        outputData[i + 1] = imgData[i + 1] + brightnessVar;
        if(outputData[i + 1] > 255) {
            outputData[i + 1] = 255;
        }
        outputData[i + 2] = imgData[i + 2] + brightnessVar;
        if(outputData[i + 2] > 255) {
            outputData[i + 2] = 255;
        }
        outputData[i + 3] = imgData[i + 3];
    }
    console.log('Output length:' + output.data.length)

    ctx.putImageData(output, 0, 0);
    this.map.render;
    this.currentImageData = output;
}
```

So this method is now called from 2 scenarios: One, when user acts on slider(ctx argument is undefined) and second, when user performs some action on image, like mouse click on image(ctx argument is defined).

'if' block right at start of the method is needed to solve the issue that if image is clicked(ie with valid ctx) original brightness is restored. So I keep track of changing pixel data(currentImageData), and if call is made with valid ctx, I just put current pixel data(currentImageData) in ctx and render the map and return.

NOTE:This gives me an impression that call made from 'postcompose' context tries to restore original pixel data. But I am not sure.

Now coming to the issue I am facing with this code: If user clicks on image, geometry features on the image are sort of duplicated. Every feature is now covered by another similar feature. And if image is panned, duplicated features can be seen(image attached).

[Duplicate features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibwqD.png)

What is the mistake I am making here?

EDIT: Raised a github issue too:
[Github issue](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/8544)

Comment: Please read [ask].  You have a really bad title.   You didn't provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you actually want is to fade or intensity the image preserving the ratios between the colours.  That can be done without individual pixel manipulation.

If you never wanted the layer brighter than it's natural state you could simply fade it use `imageLayer.setOpacity()`.

If you would like it more intense as well as fading it that can be done using a hard-light blend against a gray shade.

```
var background = 192;

imageLayer.on('precompose', function (evt) {
    evt.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'hard-light';
    evt.context.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + [background, background, background].toString() + ')';
    evt.context.fillRect(0, 0, evt.context.canvas.width, evt.context.canvas.height);
});
imageLayer.on('postcompose', function (evt) {
    evt.context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
});
```

The screenshots show background=192 (half of normal) top and background=0 (black background blend giving maximum increased intensity) bottom

You could also use a combination of hardlight blend from background=0 to 128 (normal) followed by opacity setting from 1 (normal) to 0 (transparent).

[image]

Here is a simple working demo http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/hardlight.htm